# Reactjs - material-ui radiobuttons with FormControlLabel - not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the radio buttons from material-ui - https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/

Although the example here doesn't provide the selected radio button on submitting the form. I am also trying to use redux-forms - https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/examples/material-ui/ but their documentation seems out of date. I am not sure how you would pre-select a radio button for example.

renderRadioGroup.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';


const renderRadioGroup = ({ input, label, value, fieldName, handleChange, options, meta: { touched, error }}) => (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label} {value}</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup 
        row 
        aria-label={fieldName} 
        name={fieldName} 
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        >
        {
            options.map((item, j) =>
                <FormControlLabel key={j} value={item.value} disabled={item.disabled} control={<Radio />} label={item.label} />
            )
        }
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
)

export default renderRadioGroup;
```

shell

```
  <Field 
    name="paymentplan" 
    component={renderRadioGroup} 
    label="Do you wish to pay monthly or annually?" 
    value={"1"} 
    fieldName="paymentplan" 
    options={
      [
        {
          "label" : "Monthly",
          "value" : "0"
        },
        {
          "label" : "Annually",
          "value" : "1"
        }
      ]
    }
    />
```

Comment: I suggest to use https://formik.org/ or https://react-hook-form.com/ for Forms they have good documentation.

Comment: That doesn't really help use the material-ui lib though and its animation/UI etc..  its just the radio buttons that don't seem to be taking